# Running a SELECT on a specific column that matches an input from kotlin function, throws null pointer

Tags: sqlite, kotlin

I am trying to write a method that takes a username as its input and creates a SQL query statement which is then executed. As of right now, I am getting a `NullPointer` when I try to call `result.getObject()`.

Here is my method for creating the SQL statement dynamically:

```
fun getByUsername(name: String): User?{
    val sql = """SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE username="$name";"""
    val result = DatabaseController().trySql(sql)
    if (result != null) {
        if (!result.isBeforeFirst) {
            println("User was not found...")
            return null
        } else {
            println("User found....")
            return User(result.getObject("username").toString(),
                    result.getObject("password").toString(),
                    result.getObject("admin").toString().toBoolean())
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Method that executes query:

```
fun trySql(sqlCommand: String): ResultSet? {
    var conn = this.connect()
    println("trySql()-------Running query $sqlCommand")
    var result = conn?.createStatement()?.executeQuery(sqlCommand)
    conn?.close()
    return result
}
```

The username I am running it on is in my table too, so that is not the issue. My method that creates a row in my table is working properly, so I know there is no issue with connecting to the database.

**EDIT**

If I just return `result` in `trySql()`, I no longer get any errors, but from my reading I am supposed to close connections after use?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but be careful with this method - this is a SQL Injection attack waiting to happen. You should use a `PreparedStatement` instead of manually creating the SQL. See http://bobby-tables.com for more info on SQL Injection Attacks.

Comment: I'm surprised you get a `NullPointerException` instead of a `SQLException` because you are closing the connection before reading from the result set.

Comment: @Todd It should not matter that I close it since I store the result right? Actually when I just return result, instead of closing the connection, I get no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why you are having issues

You are closing the connection, which makes the ResultSet you get back no longer useful. You will have access to the result object, but the result object will be unable to read data from SQLite, leading to errors.

## How to fix

You can pass some code to your trySql function, which will be performed with the connection still open, and then close after the passed block.

### Example

#### Library

```kotlin
class Con(val con: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL)): AutoCloseable by con {
    fun <T> withSQL(query: String, block: (ResultSet)->T): T {
        con.createStatement().use { statement ->
            statement.executeQuery(query).use { results ->
                return block(results)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```kotlin
Con().use { con ->
    val result: Int = con.withSQL("SELECT * from example WHERE name='test'") {
        it.getInt(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: I''m not quite sure what you mean? Close my connection in my `getByUsername()` method?

Comment: I'll make an example

Comment: `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")` doesn't this need to be invoked somehwere because as of right now, I am getting an error about a `No suitable driver found`. how would I got about doing that?

Comment: Which version of Java are you running on?

Comment: Java 1.8 is what I believe